# How do you use Gun as a Cowboy client?

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I followed the [Getting Started instructions](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/getting_started/) for Cowboy, and I've got Cowboy running and listening on port 8080, and I got the `Hello Erlang!` response when I entered `http://localhost:8080` in my browser.  Now, how do I use Gun to connect to Cowboy?

I read the [Gun docs](https://github.com/ninenines/gun/blob/master/doc/src/guide/start.asciidoc), and it says to add "Gun as an erlang.mk dependency".  So I downloaded erlang.mk:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ curl -O https://erlang.mk/erlang.mk
```

and following the [Erlang.mk User Guide](https://erlang.mk/guide/getting_started.html#_getting_started_with_otp_applications), I created an application:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake -f erlang.mk bootstrap
```

Then I added gun as a dependency to the Makefile:

```
PROJECT = my_gun
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = New project
PROJECT_VERSION = 0.1.0

DEPS = gun

include erlang.mk
```

Then I compiled:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
 ERLC   cow_cookie.erl cow_date.erl cow_hpack.erl cow_http.erl cow_http2.erl cow_http_hd.erl cow_http_te.erl cow_mimetypes.erl cow_multipart.erl cow_qs.erl cow_spdy.erl cow_sse.erl cow_uri.erl cow_ws.erl
 APP    cowlib
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
 DEPEND ranch.d
 ERLC   ranch.erl ranch_acceptor.erl ranch_acceptors_sup.erl ranch_app.erl ranch_conns_sup.erl ranch_listener_sup.erl ranch_protocol.erl ranch_server.erl ranch_ssl.erl ranch_sup.erl ranch_tcp.erl ranch_transport.erl
 APP    ranch
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
 DEPEND gun.d
 ERLC   gun.erl gun_app.erl gun_content_handler.erl gun_data.erl gun_http.erl gun_http2.erl gun_spdy.erl gun_sse.erl gun_sup.erl gun_ws.erl gun_ws_handler.erl
 APP    gun
 GEN    rebar.config
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
 DEPEND my_gun.d
 ERLC   my_gun_app.erl my_gun_sup.erl
 APP    my_gun
 GEN    /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/.erlang.mk/relx
===> Starting relx build process ...
===> Resolving OTP Applications from directories:
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/ebin
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps
          /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang/lib
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/apps
===> Resolved my_gun_release-1
===> rendering builtin_hook_status hook to "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/bin/hooks/builtin/status"
===> Including Erts from /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang
===> release successfully created!
===> tarball /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/my_gun_release-1.tar.gz successfully created!
```

But when I switch to the erlang shell and try to start gun, I get an error:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] 

Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)

1> application:ensure_all_started(gun).
{error,{gun,{"no such file or directory","gun.app"}}}
```

Can someone post a simple example of how to use Gun (or any other http client with websocket support) to connect to Cowboy?

---

Okay, I made some progress. I deleted the my_gun directory, recreated the directory, redownloaded erlang.mk, and created ***a release*** with the following [command](https://erlang.mk/guide/getting_started.html#_getting_started_with_otp_applications):

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake -f erlang.mk bootstrap-lib bootstrap-rel
```

Then I added the gun dependency to the Makefile (as described above).  Then I did:

```
 ~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake run
```

If there are no errors in the code, then an erlang shell will launch. In the erlang shell, I entered the following code (see the `tip` below to avoid having to type all the code in the shell):

```
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)1> application:ensure_all_started(gun).
{ok,[]}

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)2> {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080).  

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::05:21:58 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.366.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]
{ok,<0.364.0>}

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::05:21:58 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.365.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)3> {ok, Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid).
{ok,http}

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)4> gun:ws_upgrade(ConnPid, "/websocket").
#Ref<0.0.3.244>

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> receive                                          
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> {gun_ws_upgrade, ConnPid, ok, Headers} ->        
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> upgrade_success(ConnPid);
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> {gun_response, ConnPid, _, _, Status, Headers} ->
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Status, Headers});
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> {gun_error, ConnPid, StreamRef, Reason} ->
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Reason})
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> after 1000 ->
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> exit(timeout)
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)5> end.

=CRASH REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::05:25:17 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: gun:proc_lib_hack/5
    pid: <0.364.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{owner_gone,normal},
                     [{gun,loop,1,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,706}]},
                      {gun,proc_lib_hack,5,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,535}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
      in function  gun:proc_lib_hack/5 (src/gun.erl, line 540)
    ancestors: [gun_sup,<0.343.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.344.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 2586
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 10857
  neighbours:

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::05:25:17 ===
     Supervisor: {local,gun_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {{owner_gone,normal},
                  [{gun,loop,1,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,706}]},
                   {gun,proc_lib_hack,5,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,535}]},
                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.364.0>},
                  {id,gun},
                  {mfargs,{gun,start_link,undefined}},
                  {restart_type,temporary},
                  {shutdown,5000},
                  {child_type,worker}]

** exception exit: {ws_upgrade_failed,404,
                                      [{<<"content-length">>,<<"0">>},
                                       {<<"date">>,
                                        <<"Mon, 10 Jul 2017 11:22:38 GMT">>},
                                       {<<"server">>,<<"Cowboy">>}]}
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)6>
```

Now, I'm getting a 404 error.  Cowboy is running, and when I enter `http://localhost:8080 in my browser`, I see a response message.  Why is Gun giving me a 404 error?

---

Next I tried using the instructions in the [Gun docs](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/getting_started/) to make a GET request:

```
StreamRef = gun:get(ConnPid, "/").

case gun:await(ConnPid, StreamRef) of
    {response, fin, Status, Headers} ->
        no_data;
    {response, nofin, Status, Headers} ->
        {ok, Body} = gun:await_body(ConnPid, StreamRef),
        io:format("~s~n", [Body])
end.
```

and that was successful:

```
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::06:36:14 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.367.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::06:36:14 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.366.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
Hello Erlang!
ok
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)2>
```

The response means that I was able to use Gun to interact with a Cowboy server--but I want to use websockets.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

---

`tip:`

To avoid having to type all that code in the gun shell, I created the file `~/erlang_programs/my_gun/src/my.erl`:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get() ->
    {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(gun),
    {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080),
    {ok, _Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid),

    StreamRef = gun:get(ConnPid, "/"),

    case gun:await(ConnPid, StreamRef) of
        {response, fin, _Status, _Headers} ->
            no_data;
        {response, nofin, _Status, _Headers} ->
            {ok, Body} = gun:await_body(ConnPid, StreamRef),
            io:format("~s~n", [Body])
    end.

ws() ->

    {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(gun),
    {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080),
    {ok, _Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid),

    gun:ws_upgrade(ConnPid, "/websocket"),

    receive
    {gun_ws_upgrade, ConnPid, ok, Headers} ->
            upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers);
    {gun_response, ConnPid, _, _, Status, Headers} ->
            exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Status, Headers});
    {gun_error, _ConnPid, _StreamRef, Reason} ->
            exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Reason})
    %% More clauses here as needed.
    after 1000 ->
        exit(timeout)
    end,

    gun:shutdown(ConnPid).


upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers) ->
    io:format("Upgraded ~w. Success!~nHeaders:~n~p~n", 
              [ConnPid, Headers]).
```

Then the make (or gmake) command:

```
 ~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake run
```

will compile everything in the `src/` directory and alert you to any errors.  Once the gun shell successfully launches in response to `gmake run`, you can for instance do:

```
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)1> my:get().

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::06:36:14 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.367.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::06:36:14 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.366.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
Hello Erlang!
ok
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)2>
```

---

**Response to comment**:

> Since you're getting a 404, I guess you don't have a websocket handler
>   defined in the cowboy routes.

You are right.  I only had the handler shown in the Cowboy Getting Started guide.  Now, I've added the websocket setup code and a websocket handler to cowboy. I now have the routes:

hello_erlang_app.erl:

```
-module(hello_erlang_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [{"/", hello_handler, []}] },
        {'_', [{"/websocket", myws_handler, []}] }
    ]),

    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
        [{port, 8080}],
        #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch} }
    ),

    hello_erlang_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

Here's my handler:

```
-module(myws_handler).
-compile(export_all).

init(Req, State) ->
    {cowboy_websocket, Req, State}.  %Perform websocket setup

websocket_handle({text, Msg}, State) ->
    {
     reply, 
     {text, <<"Server received: ", Msg/binary>>, State}  %%Error in format here, too!
    };
websocket_handle(_Data, State) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

But I'm still getting a 404 error when I execute `my:ws()` in the gun shell:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get() ->
    {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(gun),
    {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080),
    {ok, _Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid),

    StreamRef = gun:get(ConnPid, "/"),

    case gun:await(ConnPid, StreamRef) of
        {response, fin, _Status, _Headers} ->
            no_data;
        {response, nofin, _Status, _Headers} ->
            {ok, Body} = gun:await_body(ConnPid, StreamRef),
            io:format("~s~n", [Body])
    end.

ws() ->

    {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(gun),
    {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080),
    {ok, _Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid),

    gun:ws_upgrade(ConnPid, "/websocket"),

    receive
        {gun_ws_upgrade, ConnPid, ok, Headers} ->
            upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers);
        {gun_response, ConnPid, _, _, Status, Headers} ->
            exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Status, Headers});
        {gun_error, _ConnPid, _StreamRef, Reason} ->
            exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Reason})
    %% More clauses here as needed.
    after 1000 ->
        exit(timeout)
    end,

    gun:shutdown(ConnPid).


upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers) ->
    io:format("Upgraded ~w. Success!~nHeaders:~n~w~n", 
              [ConnPid, Headers]).
```

Here's the output:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake run
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
 GEN    rebar.config
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
 DEPEND my_gun.d
 ERLC   my.erl
 APP    my_gun
===> Starting relx build process ...
===> Resolving OTP Applications from directories:
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/ebin
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps
          /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang/lib
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/apps
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel
===> Resolved my_gun_release-1
===> rendering builtin_hook_status hook to "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/bin/hooks/builtin/status"
===> Including Erts from /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang
===> release successfully created!
===> tarball /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/my_gun_release-1.tar.gz successfully created!
Exec: /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/erts-8.2/bin/erlexec -boot /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/my_gun_release -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/lib -config /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/sys.config -args_file /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/vm.args -pa -- console
Root: /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release
/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release
heart_beat_kill_pid = 32843
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]


=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:05 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.353.0>},
                       {id,alarm_handler},
                       {mfargs,{alarm_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:05 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.352.0>},
                       {id,sasl_safe_sup},
                       {mfargs,
                           {supervisor,start_link,
                               [{local,sasl_safe_sup},sasl,safe]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,infinity},
                       {child_type,supervisor}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:05 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.354.0>},
                       {id,release_handler},
                       {mfargs,{release_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:05 ===
         application: sasl
          started_at: 'my_gun@127.0.0.1'

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:05 ===
          supervisor: {local,runtime_tools_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.360.0>},
                       {id,ttb_autostart},
                       {mfargs,{ttb_autostart,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,3000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:05 ===
         application: runtime_tools
          started_at: 'my_gun@127.0.0.1'
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)1> my:ws().

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:08 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.367.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:08 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.366.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=CRASH REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:08 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: gun:proc_lib_hack/5
    pid: <0.365.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{owner_gone,normal},
                     [{gun,loop,1,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,706}]},
                      {gun,proc_lib_hack,5,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,535}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
      in function  gun:proc_lib_hack/5 (src/gun.erl, line 540)
    ancestors: [gun_sup,<0.345.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.346.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 610
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 1042
  neighbours:

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:26:08 ===
     Supervisor: {local,gun_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {{owner_gone,normal},
                  [{gun,loop,1,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,706}]},
                   {gun,proc_lib_hack,5,[{file,"src/gun.erl"},{line,535}]},
                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.365.0>},
                  {id,gun},
                  {mfargs,{gun,start_link,undefined}},
                  {restart_type,temporary},
                  {shutdown,5000},
                  {child_type,worker}]

** exception exit: {ws_upgrade_failed,404,
                                      [{<<"content-length">>,<<"0">>},
                                       {<<"date">>,
                                        <<"Mon, 10 Jul 2017 22:26:08 GMT">>},
                                       {<<"server">>,<<"Cowboy">>}]}
     in function  my:ws/0 (src/my.erl, line 30)

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)2>
```

I saved all my files and restarted cowboy and gun, so the changes I made to the code are being executed, but I still get the 404 error.

---

I compared the format of my routes to the routes in the example that spawn_think linked to in the comments, and my format was wrong.  Here is what I have now:

```
-module(hello_erlang_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [
               {"/", hello_handler, []},
               {"/websocket", myws_handler, []} 
        ]}
    ]),

    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
        [{port, 8080}],
        #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch} }
    ),

    hello_erlang_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

And after adjusting one of the control sequences in the io:format() statement in my gun client:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get() ->
    ...

ws() ->
    ...

upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers) ->
    io:format("Upgraded ~w. Success!~nHeaders:~n~p~n",   %% <*** CHANGED ~w to ~p 
              [ConnPid, Headers]).
```

here is the output:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake run
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
 GEN    rebar.config
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
 DEPEND my_gun.d
 ERLC   my.erl
 APP    my_gun
===> Starting relx build process ...
===> Resolving OTP Applications from directories:
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/ebin
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps
          /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang/lib
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/apps
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel
===> Resolved my_gun_release-1
===> rendering builtin_hook_status hook to "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/bin/hooks/builtin/status"
===> Including Erts from /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang
===> release successfully created!
===> tarball /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/my_gun_release-1.tar.gz successfully created!
Exec: /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/erts-8.2/bin/erlexec -boot /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/my_gun_release -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/lib -config /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/sys.config -args_file /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/vm.args -pa -- console
Root: /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release
/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release
heart_beat_kill_pid = 34141
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]


=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:53 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.353.0>},
                       {id,alarm_handler},
                       {mfargs,{alarm_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:53 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.352.0>},
                       {id,sasl_safe_sup},
                       {mfargs,
                           {supervisor,start_link,
                               [{local,sasl_safe_sup},sasl,safe]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,infinity},
                       {child_type,supervisor}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:53 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.354.0>},
                       {id,release_handler},
                       {mfargs,{release_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:53 ===
         application: sasl
          started_at: 'my_gun@127.0.0.1'

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:53 ===
          supervisor: {local,runtime_tools_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.360.0>},
                       {id,ttb_autostart},
                       {mfargs,{ttb_autostart,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,3000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:53 ===
         application: runtime_tools
          started_at: 'my_gun@127.0.0.1'
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)1> my:ws().

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:57 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.367.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::16:50:57 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.366.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
Upgraded <0.365.0>. Success!
Headers:
[{<<"connection">>,<<"Upgrade">>},
 {<<"date">>,<<"Mon, 10 Jul 2017 22:50:56 GMT">>},
 {<<"sec-websocket-accept">>,<<"S1w7rWXToZefi/NOEcDAEDb4yEU=">>},
 {<<"server">>,<<"Cowboy">>},
 {<<"upgrade">>,<<"websocket">>}]
ok
(my_gun@127.0.0.1)2>
```

---

I've reached the forum's limit on text, so see my answer for how I was actually able to send and receive data using a websocket.

Comment: To start, you need to have the path to beam and .app files discoverable to the shell. You can either do it manually by using -p flag when starting it or you can run the release using make run

Comment: @spawn_think, Thanks for taking a look.  I made some progress.  Now I'm getting a 404 error.  I added what's happening now to the end of my question.

Comment: Since you're getting a 404, I guess you don't have a websocket handler defined in the cowboy routes. You can see an example in https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/websocket

Comment: P.S: it would help if you post the cowboy routes you have defined.

Comment: @spawn_think, I posted my current problems.

Comment: @spawn_think, Okay.  The format of my routes was off: I looked at the example you posted and copied that format.  The upgrade is now a success.  I'll continue working on my example to see if I can actually transmit some data through the websocket.

Comment: @spawn_think, Can you post your last comment as an answer, so I can accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success!

~/erlang_programs/my_gun/src/my.erl:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get() ->
    ...

ws() ->

    {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(gun),
    {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080),
    {ok, _Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid),

    gun:ws_upgrade(ConnPid, "/websocket"),

    receive
        {gun_ws_upgrade, ConnPid, ok, Headers} ->
                upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers);
        {gun_response, ConnPid, _, _, Status, Headers} ->
                exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Status, Headers});
        {gun_error, _ConnPid, _StreamRef, Reason} ->
                exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Reason})
        %% More clauses here as needed.
    after 1000 ->
            exit(timeout)
    end,


upgrade_success(ConnPid, Headers) ->
    io:format("Upgraded ~w. Success!~nHeaders:~n~p~n", 
              [ConnPid, Headers]),

    gun:ws_send(ConnPid, {text, "It's raining!"}),

    receive
        {gun_ws, ConnPid, {text, Msg} } ->
            io:format("~s~n", [Msg])
    end.
```

On the cowboy side:

```
-module(myws_handler).
-compile(export_all).

init(Req, State) ->
    {cowboy_websocket, Req, State}.  %Perform websocket setup

websocket_handle({text, Msg}, State) ->
    {
     reply, 
     {text, io_lib:format("Server received: ~s", [Msg]) },
     State
    };
websocket_handle(_Other, State) ->  %Ignore
    {ok, State}.
```

Here's the output:

```
~/erlang_programs/my_gun$ gmake run
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/cowlib'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/ranch'
 GEN    rebar.config
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps/gun'
 DEPEND my_gun.d
 ERLC   my.erl
 APP    my_gun
===> Starting relx build process ...
===> Resolving OTP Applications from directories:
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/ebin
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/deps
          /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang/lib
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/apps
          /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel
===> Resolved my_gun_release-1
===> rendering builtin_hook_status hook to "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/bin/hooks/builtin/status"
===> Including Erts from /Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/lib/erlang
===> release successfully created!
===> tarball /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/my_gun_release-1.tar.gz successfully created!
Exec: /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/erts-8.2/bin/erlexec -boot /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/my_gun_release -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/lib -config /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/sys.config -args_file /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release/releases/1/vm.args -pa -- console
Root: /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release
/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/my_gun/_rel/my_gun_release
heart_beat_kill_pid = 38883
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]


=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:38 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.353.0>},
                       {id,alarm_handler},
                       {mfargs,{alarm_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:38 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.352.0>},
                       {id,sasl_safe_sup},
                       {mfargs,
                           {supervisor,start_link,
                               [{local,sasl_safe_sup},sasl,safe]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,infinity},
                       {child_type,supervisor}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:38 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.354.0>},
                       {id,release_handler},
                       {mfargs,{release_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:38 ===
         application: sasl
          started_at: 'my_gun@127.0.0.1'

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:38 ===
          supervisor: {local,runtime_tools_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.360.0>},
                       {id,ttb_autostart},
                       {mfargs,{ttb_autostart,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,3000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:38 ===
         application: runtime_tools
          started_at: 'my_gun@127.0.0.1'
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)1> my:ws().

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:41 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.367.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::18:04:41 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.366.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
Upgraded <0.365.0>. Success!
Headers:
[{<<"connection">>,<<"Upgrade">>},
 {<<"date">>,<<"Tue, 11 Jul 2017 00:04:40 GMT">>},
 {<<"sec-websocket-accept">>,<<"pYv8QeeJfzQgaS/x8flZHyrIexk=">>},
 {<<"server">>,<<"Cowboy">>},
 {<<"upgrade">>,<<"websocket">>}]
Server received: It's raining!
ok

(my_gun@127.0.0.1)2>
```

Answer (score 2):

A summary of the issues/suggestions from the comments discussion

1. For running your Erlang app (in this case including gun as a dependency), you need to have the path to beam and .app files discoverable to the shell. When using erlang.mk, the easiest way to do that would be running the release using `make run`
2. On Cowboy side, to have Websocket handled correctly, you need to have a handler defined in your cowboy routes. See example in [Cowboy Websocket example](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/websocket)

See also [Gun user guide](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/gun/1.0/guide/websocket/) for more details about handling Websocket in Gun