# What is the easiest way to communicate between Javascript web script to an Erlang server

Tags: javascript, json, websocket, erlang, cowboy

Hi I am taking a course on Erlang, and for the final project I decided to make web game.
I am using cowboy for the server written in Erlang, and I am stuck in the process of transfering data between the client and the server.
I am able to successfully establish a websocket connection, but I find it hard to transfer json data.

How can I get the information sent by the client to the server side?

The client websocket connection is established like this:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/websocket");
socket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
```

And the client sends json:

```
var data = {x_val: x,y_val: y};
socket.send(data);
```

The code for the cowboy server with a websocket handler

```
-module(ws_handler).

-export([init/2]).
-export([websocket_init/1]).
-export([websocket_handle/2]).
-export([websocket_info/2]).

init(Req, Opts) ->
    {cowboy_websocket, Req, Opts}.

websocket_init(State) ->
    io:fwrite("connection establish !~n", []),
    erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), <<"Hello!">>),
    {ok, State}.

websocket_handle({text, Msg}, State) ->
    {reply, {text, << "That's what she said! ", Msg/binary >>}, State};


websocket_handle(_Data, State) ->
     io:format("_Data -> Erlang\n~p\n",[_Data]),
    {ok, State}.

websocket_info({timeout, _Ref, Msg}, State) ->
    erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), <<"How' you doin'?">>),
    {reply, {text, Msg}, State};


websocket_info(_Info, State) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Comment: Your code seems to come straight from Cowboy's example: https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/websocket
Did you manage to run the above example without modifications, first?

Comment: See if any of this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005984/how-do-you-use-gun-as-a-cowboy-client

Answer (score 2):

i found this example

https://lookonmyworks.co.uk/2014/12/21/hello-world-with-cowboy-and-websockets/

i I updated accordingly the ws_handler

```
-module(ws_handler).


-export([init/2]).
-export([websocket_init/1]).
-export([websocket_handle/2]).
-export([websocket_info/2]).



init(Req, Opts) ->
    {cowboy_websocket, Req, Opts}.

websocket_init(State) ->
    io:fwrite("connection establish !~n", []),
    erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), <<"Hello!">>),
    {ok, State}.


websocket_handle({text, Json}, State) ->
    Map = jiffy:decode(Json, [return_maps]),
     X_val = maps:get(<<"x_val">>, Map),
     Y_val = maps:get(<<"y_val">>, Map),
     Reply = #{x_val =>X_val, y_val =>Y_val},
     {reply, {text, jiffy:encode(Reply)}, State}.



websocket_info({timeout, _Ref, Msg}, State) ->
    erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), <<"How' you doin'?">>),
    {reply, {text, Msg}, State};


websocket_info(_Info, State) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

and for the client reacive i used

```
function onMessage(ev) {

 var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data);
 spaceShip.v_pos.set( msg.x, msg.y);}
```

and client transmit

```
y = y + angle_sine*0.2*sin(angle);
x = x + angle_sine*0.2*cos(angle);

var data = {x_val: x, y_val: y };
socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```