# Using Cowboy Websocket Client for Testing with Elixir

Tags: websocket, erlang, elixir, client

First of all, there is a genuine lack of documentation for Cowboy altogether and Websockets in particular but in general it is excellent to use once it is decyphered. Then getting that info from Erlang to Elixir is another step. Thanks to [this post by 7stud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45023350/438322) I was able to get a functioning websocket going for testing purposes but I can't get it to listen and optionally send messages at the same time. I think this is because receive is blocking the thread which is needed to send and this is intrinsically linked to to the websocket connection so it can't send while it's waiting to receive. Maybe this understanding is flawed. I would love to be corrected. I have tried spawning to no avail which is why I am thinking the receive is blocking the websocket thread.

```
def ws do
    localhost = 'localhost'
    path = '/ws/app/1'
    port = 5000

    {:ok, _} = :application.ensure_all_started(:gun)
    connect_opts = %{
      connect_timeout: :timer.minutes(1),
      retry: 10,
      retry_timeout: 100
    }

    {:ok, conn_pid} = :gun.open(localhost, port, connect_opts)
    IO.inspect(conn_pid, label: "conn_pid")
    {:ok, protocol} = :gun.await_up(conn_pid)
    IO.inspect(protocol, label: "protocol")
    # Set custom header with cookie for device id
    stream_ref = :gun.ws_upgrade(conn_pid, path, [{"cookie", "device_id=1235"}])
    IO.inspect(stream_ref, label: "stream_ref")
    receive do
      {:gun_upgrade, ^conn_pid, ^stream_ref, ["websocket"], headers} ->
              upgrade_success(conn_pid, headers, stream_ref)
      {:gun_response, ^conn_pid, _, _, status, headers} ->
              exit({:ws_upgrade_failed, status, headers})
      {:gun_error, _conn_pid, _stream_ref, reason} ->
              exit({:ws_upgrade_failed, reason})
      whatever ->
        IO.inspect(whatever, label: "Whatever")
      # More clauses here as needed.
    after 5000 ->
        IO.puts "Took too long!"
        :erlang.exit("barf!")
    end
    :ok
  end

  def upgrade_success(conn_pid, headers, stream_ref) do
    IO.puts("Upgraded #{inspect(conn_pid)}. Success!\nHeaders:\n#{inspect(headers)}\n")

    IO.inspect(self(), label: "upgrade self")
    # This one runs and message is received
    run_test(conn_pid)
    # This should spawn and therefore not block
    listen(conn_pid, stream_ref)
    # This never runs
    run_test(conn_pid)
  end

  def listen(conn_pid, stream_ref) do
    spawn receive_messages(conn_pid, stream_ref)
  end
  def receive_messages(conn_pid, stream_ref) do
    IO.inspect conn_pid, label: "conn_pid!"
    IO.inspect stream_ref, label: "stream_ref!"
    IO.inspect(self(), label: "self pid")
    receive do
      {:gun_ws, ^conn_pid, ^stream_ref, {:text, msg} } ->
          IO.inspect(msg, label: "Message from websocket server:")
      other_messages ->
        IO.inspect(other_messages, label: "Other messages")
    after 5000 ->
      IO.puts "Receive timed out"
    end
    receive_messages(conn_pid, stream_ref)
  end

  def send_message(message, conn_pid) do
    :gun.ws_send(conn_pid, {:text, message})
  end

  def run_test(conn_pid) do
    IO.puts "Running test"
    message = "{\"type\":\"init\",\"body\":{\"device_id\":1234}}"
    send_message(message, conn_pid)
  end

  def stop(conn_pid) do
    :gun.shutdown(conn_pid)
  end
```

Comment: *I think this is because receive is blocking the thread which is needed to send and this is intrinsically linked to to the websocket connection so it can't send while it's waiting to receive. Maybe this understanding is flawed.* -- Yes, I think it must be flawed, because of what's stated here: https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.1/guide/ws_protocol/.  ***With Websocket, the client and the server can both send frames at any time without any restriction.***

Comment: *I was able to get a functioning websocket going for testing purposes but I can't get it to listen and optionally send messages at the same time.* -- What does `it` refer to in that sentence?  The server or the client?

Comment: @7stud I've already got a server running. Now I'm trying to get a working client. By 'server' I mean the program that waits to receive websocket connections from various clients.

Comment: For anyone interested I finished this and you can take a look at this repo if you're looking for a more complete example. https://github.com/GamgeeNL/websocket-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 7stud for the example code and the edits which are reflected below:

Here is my Elixir interpretation to give a basic WebSocket client for gun:

```
defmodule WebsocketTester.Application do

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do

    path = '/ws/app/1'

    port = 5000

    host = 'localhost'

    args = %{path: path, port: port, host: host}

    children = [
      { WebSocket.Client, args }
    ]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one, name: WebsocketTester.Supervisor)
  end
end

defmodule WebSocket.Client do

  use GenServer

  def child_spec(opts) do
    %{
      id: __MODULE__,
      start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, [opts]},
      type: :worker,
      restart: :permanent,
      shutdown: 500
    }
  end

  def start_link(args) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  # GenServer callbacks

  def init(args) do
    # Set up the websocket connection
    # get > upgrade
    # Initial state with gun_pid and stream_ref
    # %{gun_pid: gun_pid, stream_ref: stream_ref} = ws(args)
    {:ok, init_ws(args)}
  end

  # Give back gun_pid from state
  def handle_call(:get_conn, from, %{gun_pid: gun_pid, stream_ref: stream_ref}) do
    IO.inspect(gun_pid, label: "handle call gun pid")
    {:reply, %{gun_pid: gun_pid, stream_ref: stream_ref}, %{from: from, gun_pid: gun_pid} }
  end
  # Everything else
  def handle_call(other, from, state) do
    IO.inspect(other, label: "other call")
    IO.inspect(from, label: "from")
    {:ok, state}
  end
  # Client sends message to server.
  def handle_cast({:websocket_request, message}, %{gun_pid: gun_pid} = state) do
    IO.puts message
    IO.inspect(gun_pid, label: "gun_pid")
    :gun.ws_send(gun_pid, {:text, message})
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info(message, %{from: from} = state) do
    IO.inspect(message, label: "Inside handle_info(): ")
    GenServer.reply(from, message)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def terminate(reason, _state) do
    IO.puts "Terminated due to #{reason}."
    :ok
  end


  def code_change(_old_version, state, _extra) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  ## Client functions
  # Used for getting gun_pid from state
  def send_sync(request) do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, request)
  end

  # Send a message async
  def send_async(request) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:websocket_request, request})
  end

  # Receive a single message
  def get_message(stream_ref, gun_pid) do
      receive do
          {^stream_ref, {:gun_ws, ^gun_pid, {:text, message} }} ->
              IO.puts("Client received gun message: #{message}")
          other ->
            IO.inspect(other, label: "Client received other message")
      end
  end

  # Receive all messages recursively
  def receive_loop(stream_ref, gun_pid) do
    IO.puts "Listening"
      get_message(stream_ref, gun_pid)
      receive_loop(stream_ref, gun_pid)
  end

  def go() do
    # Get the gun_pid from state
    %{gun_pid: gun_pid, stream_ref: stream_ref} = send_sync(:get_gun_pid)
    IO.inspect(gun_pid, label: "Inside go(): gun_pid=")
    # Send messages manually
    :ok = send_async(Jason.encode!(%{type: "info", greet: "yo"}))
    # Or to send just text
    # :ok = send_async("yo")

    # Receive messages manually
    get_message(stream_ref, gun_pid)

    # Start sending loop
    spawn sender 1

    # Start listening
    receive_loop(stream_ref, gun_pid)
  end

  # Send messages to handle_info() every 3 secs
  def sender(count) do
      send_async("count is #{count}")
      :timer.sleep(3000)
      sender(count+1)
  end

  ## End of client functions

  # Initialize the websocket connection
  def init_ws(args) do

    %{ path: path, port: port, host: host} = args

    {:ok, _} = :application.ensure_all_started(:gun)
    connect_opts = %{
      connect_timeout: :timer.minutes(1),
      retry: 10,
      retry_timeout: 100
    }

    {:ok, gun_pid} = :gun.open(host, port, connect_opts)
    {:ok, _protocol} = :gun.await_up(gun_pid)
    # Set custom header with cookie for device id - set_headers can be left out if you don't want custom headers
    stream_ref = :gun.ws_upgrade(gun_pid, path, set_headers("I like cookies"))
    receive do
      {:gun_upgrade, ^gun_pid, ^stream_ref, ["websocket"], headers} ->
            upgrade_success(gun_pid, headers, stream_ref)
      {:gun_response, ^gun_pid, _, _, status, headers} ->
              exit({:ws_upgrade_failed, status, headers})
      {:gun_error, _gun_pid, _stream_ref, reason} ->
              exit({:ws_upgrade_failed, reason})
      whatever ->
        IO.inspect(whatever, label: "Whatever")
      # More clauses here as needed.
    after 5000 ->
        IO.puts "Took too long!"
        :erlang.exit("barf!")
    end
    # stop(gun_pid)
  end


  def set_headers(cookie_value) do
    [{"cookie", "my_cookie=#{cookie_value}"}]
  end

  # This just returns the gun_pid for further reference which gets stored in the GenServer state.
  def upgrade_success(gun_pid, headers, stream_ref) do
    IO.puts("Upgraded #{inspect(gun_pid)}. Success!\nHeaders:\n#{inspect(headers)}\n")
    %{stream_ref: stream_ref, gun_pid: gun_pid}
  end

  # To stop gun
  def stop(gun_pid) do
    :gun.shutdown(gun_pid)
  end

end
```

To use this:

```
iex -S mix
iex> WebSocket.Client.go
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to make some changes.  `gen_server:call()` creates a unique ref to identify the client, which `gen_server:reply/2` returns with its message.  I was ignoring the Ref in the client's receive clause, but it's better to pattern match that Ref so that the client knows the message is from the gen_server and not some other process.  Now, `handle_call()` returns both the ConnPid and the ClientRef, which means the client can use the ClientRef in the receive to make sure the messages are from the gen_server.

Answer (score 1):

From the [gun docs](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/gun/1.3/guide/websocket/):

> **Receiving data**
>
> Gun sends an Erlang message to the ***owner process*** for every Websocket
>   message it receives.

[and](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/gun/1.3/guide/connect/):

> **Connection**
>
> ...
>
> Gun connections
>
> ...
>
> A Gun connection is an Erlang process that manages a socket to a
>   remote endpoint. This Gun connection is owned by a user process that
>   is called the owner of the connection, and is managed by the
>   supervision tree of the gun application.
>
> The owner process communicates with the Gun connection by calling
>   functions from the module gun. All functions perform their respective
>   operations asynchronously. The Gun connection will send Erlang
>   messages to the owner process whenever needed.

Although it's not specifically mentioned in the docs, I'm pretty sure the **owner process** is the process that calls `gun:open()`.  My attempts also reveal that the owner process has to call `gun:ws_send()`.  In other words, the owner process has to both send messages to the server and receive the messages from the server.

The following code operates gun with a `gen_server` in such a way that the gen_server both sends messages to the server and receives messages from the server.

When gun receives a message from the cowboy http server, gun sends the message, i.e. `Pid ! Msg`, to the owner process.  In the following code, the `gen_server` creates the connection in the `init/1` callback, which means that gun will bang (!) messages that it receives from cowboy at the `gen_server`.  A gen_server handles messages sent directly to its mailbox with `handle_info()`.

In `handle_cast()`, the `gen_server` uses gun to send requests to cowboy.  Because `handle_cast()` is asynchronous, that means you are able to send asynchronous messages to cowboy. And, when gun receives a message from cowboy, gun sends(!) the message to the gen_server, and the gen_server's `handle_info()` function handles the message.  Inside `handle_info()`, `gen_server:reply/2` is called to relay the message to the `gen_server` client.  As a result, the `gen_server` client can jump into a receive clause whenever it wants to check the server messages sent from gun.

```
-module(client).
-behavior(gen_server).
-export([start_server/0, send_sync/1, send_async/1, get_message/2, go/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2]).
-export([terminate/2, code_change/3]).  %%% client functions
-export([sender/1]).

%%% client functions
%%%

start_server() ->
    gen_server:start({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

send_sync(Requ) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, Requ).

send_async(Requ) -> 
    gen_server:cast(?MODULE, {websocket_request, Requ}).

get_message(WebSocketPid, ClientRef) ->
    receive
        {ClientRef, {gun_ws, WebSocketPid, {text, Msg} }} ->
            io:format("Inside get_message(): Ref = ~w~n", [ClientRef]),
            io:format("Client received gun message: ~s~n", [Msg]);
        Other ->
            io:format("Client received other message: ~w~n", [Other])
    end.

receive_loop(WebSocketPid, ClientRef) ->
    receive
        {ClientRef, {gun_ws, WebSocketPid, {text, Msg} }} ->
            io:format("Client received Gun message: ~s~n", [Msg]);
        Other ->
            io:format("Client received other message: ~w~n", [Other])
    end,
    receive_loop(WebSocketPid, ClientRef).

go() ->
    {ok, GenServerPid} = start_server(),
    io:format("[ME]: Inside go(): GenServerPid=~w~n", [GenServerPid]),

    [{conn_pid, ConnPid}, {ref, ClientRef}] = send_sync(get_conn_pid),
    io:format("[ME]: Inside go(): ConnPid=~w~n", [ConnPid]),

    ok = send_async("ABCD"),
    get_message(ConnPid, ClientRef),

    spawn(?MODULE, sender, [1]),

    ok = send_async("XYZ"),
    get_message(ConnPid, ClientRef),

    receive_loop(ConnPid, ClientRef).

sender(Count) -> %Send messages to handle_info() every 3 secs
    send_async(lists:concat(["Hello", Count])),
    timer:sleep(3000),
    sender(Count+1).

%%%%%% gen_server callbacks
%%%

init(_Arg) ->
    {ok, {no_client, ws()}}.

handle_call(get_conn_pid, From={_ClientPid, ClientRef}, _State={_Client, WebSocketPid}) ->
    io:format("[ME]: Inside handle_call(): From = ~w~n", [From]),
    {reply, [{conn_pid, WebSocketPid}, {ref, ClientRef}], _NewState={From, WebSocketPid} };
handle_call(stop, _From, State) ->
    {stop, normal, shutdown_ok, State}; %Calls terminate()
handle_call(_Other, _From, State) ->
    {ok, State}.

handle_cast({websocket_request, Msg}, State={_From, WebSocketPid}) ->
    gun:ws_send(WebSocketPid, {text, Msg}), %{text, "It's raining!"}),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(Msg, State={From, _WebSocketPid}) ->
    io:format("[ME]: Inside handle_info(): Msg=~w~n", [Msg]),
    gen_server:reply(From, Msg),
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State={_From, WebSocketPid}) -> 
    gun:shutdown(WebSocketPid).


code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.


%%%% private functions
%%%

ws() ->
    {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(gun),
    {ok, ConnPid} = gun:open("localhost", 8080),
    {ok, _Protocol} = gun:await_up(ConnPid),

    gun:ws_upgrade(ConnPid, "/please_upgrade_to_websocket"),

    receive
        {gun_ws_upgrade, ConnPid, ok, Headers} ->
            io:format("[ME]: Inside gun_ws_upgrade receive clause: ~w~n", 
                      [ConnPid]),
            upgrade_success_handler(ConnPid, Headers);
        {gun_response, ConnPid, _, _, Status, Headers} ->
            exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Status, Headers});
        {gun_error, _ConnPid, _StreamRef, Reason} ->
            exit({ws_upgrade_failed, Reason})
    after 1000 ->
        exit(timeout)
    end.


upgrade_success_handler(ConnPid, _Headers) ->
    io:format("[ME]: Inside upgrade_success_handler(): ~w~n", [ConnPid]),  
    ConnPid.
```

=======

***Whoops, the answer below shows how to get the server to push data to the client.***

Okay, I got it--in erlang.  This example is a little bit tortured. You need to do a couple of things:

1) You need to get the pid of the process running the `websocket_*` functions, which is not the same as the pid of the request:

> **Post-upgrade initialization**
>
> Cowboy has separate processes for handling the connection and
>   requests. Because Websocket takes over the connection, the Websocket
>   protocol handling occurs in a different process than the request
>   handling.
>
> This is reflected in the different callbacks Websocket handlers have.
>   The init/2 callback is called from the temporary request process and
>   the websocket_ callbacks from the connection process.
>
> This means that some initialization cannot be done from init/2.
>   Anything that would require the current pid, or be tied to the current
>   pid, will not work as intended. The optional websocket_init/1 can be
>   used [to get the pid of the process running the websocket_ callbacks]:

https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.6/guide/ws_handlers/

Here's the code I used:

```
init(Req, State) ->
    {cowboy_websocket, Req, State}.  %Perform websocket setup

websocket_init(State) ->
    io:format("[ME]: Inside websocket_init"),
    spawn(?MODULE, push, [self(), "Hi, there"]),
    {ok, State}.

push(WebSocketHandleProcess, Greeting) ->
    timer:sleep(4000),
    WebSocketHandleProcess ! {text, Greeting}.

websocket_handle({text, Msg}, State) ->
    timer:sleep(10000), %Don't respond to client request just yet.
    {
     reply, 
     {text, io_lib:format("Server received: ~s", [Msg]) },
     State
    };
websocket_handle(_Other, State) ->  %Ignore
    {ok, State}.
```

That will push a message to the client while the client is waiting for a reply to a request that the client previously sent to the server.

2) If you send a message to the process that is running the `websocket_*` functions:

```
Pid ! {text, Msg}
```

then that message will get handled by the `websocket_info()` function--not the `websocket_handle()` function:

```
websocket_info({text, Text}, State) ->
    {reply, {text, Text}, State};
websocket_info(_Other, State) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

The return value of the `websocket_info()` function works just like the return value of the `websocket_handle()` function.

Because your gun client is now receiving multiple messages, the gun client needs to receive in a loop:

```
upgrade_success_handler(ConnPid, Headers) ->
    io:format("Upgraded ~w. Success!~nHeaders:~n~p~n", 
              [ConnPid, Headers]),

    gun:ws_send(ConnPid, {text, "It's raining!"}),

    get_messages(ConnPid).  %Move the receive clause into a recursive function

get_messages(ConnPid) ->
    receive
        {gun_ws, ConnPid, {text, "Greeting: " ++ Greeting} } ->
            io:format("~s~n", [Greeting]),
            get_messages(ConnPid);

        {gun_ws, ConnPid, {text, Msg} } ->
            io:format("~s~n", [Msg]),
            get_messages(ConnPid)
    end.
```

Comment: Thank you! Edits are reflected in my answer.

Comment: @GenericJam, Good work translating!  If you don't mind, edit your question and add `erlang` and `gun` tags--it will make the info easier to find for erlangers.

Comment: I added `erlang` and `erlang-gun` as `gun` refers to gun db. I removed `cowboy` as it isn't strictly cowboy and I had to keep it to 5 tags.